# Release Connection From Application

Tags: java

I have a web application from which we enable "Download links" after a filter search.Once the user clicks on the download link, we create a connection from the pool and stream the data from Teradata into the Outputstream and then write int Excel sheet. The prompt to open or save or cancel is shown as part of windows once download link is clicked.Open or Save cases have the same things to do while if the user is cancelling the download in the popup window we need to release the connection.But since the pop up is windows default action, how to capture it and have the release connection done?

Please let me know if anyone has faced the same thing since its P1 issue for us now.It keeps many threads open and the application is hung after a period of time.

Comment: What is the relationship between Java and your question?

Comment: Since We are developing a java web application,it is related to java. Next is because from our application the connection is created I need to also close the connection from the application only as the thread gets hung due to multiple connections.Is there anyway to do this??